# Single Account for Multiple Application login in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm building some applications using rails. 
All apps using restful auth plugin for User base and declarative authorization plugin for authorization rules.

But I need to merge all site's User accounts to one User base for providing login for all sites.

I.e like 37signals working on. Here is their work ; 
http://37signals.com/accounts

How can I archieve this, any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks
A.Karr

Comment: hi @AKarr - you seem new here, so I thought I should say - it's generally considered Good Form to "accept" an answer hat has helped to solve your problem. You can do that by clicking the "tick" to the left of the answer. It helps give the answerer a little boost, and makes it more likely that your future questions will get answered. :)

Answer (score 3):

From studying how 37signals was doing stuff - I think they're using RubyCAS http://github.com/gunark/rubycas-server

It's perfect for single sign-on, single sign-off and other related stuff - when you have multiple independent applications. Also, because CAS is a generic protocol, it exists for non-ruby/rails applications too. SO you can integrate legacy systems or client applications in Java etc.

I started building a set of how-tos on the subject here:
http://rubyglasses.blogspot.com/2009/12/rails-single-sign-on-with-rubycas.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using open id?

If all your apps run on the same domain you shouldn't have any problems accessing the authentication cookie in all the apps, but you'll need to store the authentication state somewhere where all the applications can access it.